# The Atkin Sieve

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers

I've been curious about the Sieve of Atkin for a while now, and it occurred to me that it essentially generates numbers using specified quadratic forms, and then sieves out multiples of the squares of them because the primes will be precisely the square-free ones.  My question is if there is a more general sieving algorithm, perhaps using different quadratic forms, different factorization conditions, or even a larger initial wheel-factorization.

Comment: If we consider only the two arithmetic progressions (AP) $(6k+1)$ and $(6k-1)$ and identify, not the primes, but the composites by considering the 3 different products $(6x+1)*(6y+1)$, $(6x-1)*(6y-1)$ and $(6x-1)*(6y+1)$, then setup the matrices for these products. Before that, you index the elements of both AP (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...) then set the matrices of indexes. For example 7*7 becomes 49 but is represented by (49-1)/6=8. So we know that position 8 is in the original indexing of the $(6k+1)$ is a composite. If you are interested, I can provide more details.